# Upgraded to Glassfish 4.1 - Now error while deploying EAR with Swing app packaged - Can't find resource for PropertyResourceBundle

Tags: java, swing, glassfish, ear, glassfish-4

The full error from the log is:

**org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key enterprise.deployment.appclient.noManifest**

The relevant stack trace is:

```
[2014-09-15T16:28:09.695-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=48 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1410816489695] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key enterprise.deployment.appclient.noManifest
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
```

I have a basic EAR with an EJB in it, and a Swing app also in it.

When I deploy with just the EJB, everything works fine. When I add the Swing app, it fails with this error.

It was working before I used this [tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/quinn/entry/glassfish_java_web_start_and) to change the keystore to have a secure certificate rather than the self signing.

Is it possible that the new signing for java web start is causing the manifest to not be created?

Comment: for my info, how are you creating the swing app?  as an ACC client, or stand-alone?

Comment: it is packages in the EAR

Comment: pardon to hijack your q, but I'm at wits end.  I followed https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html and it packages EAR, deploys EAR.  then what?

Comment: Then in Glassfish click on your Application and find your App Client, then click Launch and then download your Launch file. Click on that and Java Web Start will open it.